# how to view multiple images with the webviewer in appinventor?

Tags: app-inventor

[image]

my code is above But the images are not shown. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be only one URL at a time. You're entering two URLs together. It does not work like a slide show. Web viewer can handle only one URL at a time.

But to view two images, you can have two ways.

i) Get 2 web viewers and assign different path to them.

ii) create 2 buttons and set property:

```
on button1.press-> set webviewer.url to image 1
on button2.press-> set webviewer.url to image 2
```

Hope you got the point here.

I thought of another alternative here. 
Just create an HTML document with all your image. And set web viewer URL to that HTML page.(of course you need to include that HTML file)

Comment: I do not know how to create an html file. :(

Comment: then using the buttons for different images will be easier for you:)